# GTK+ 3.0 and C programm

Tags: c, gtk

I'm a beginner programmer in C/C++. ;) Recently on the Internet I found information about GTK and so on. Also I found this site: (http://wingtk.sourceforge.net/ishan/sliders.html). I wanted to run this code,  but my compiler says something like this in 231 line (in sliders.c): "GtkWidget has no member named 'parent'", I don't understand, what's wrong with this program. I tried to fix this, but I failed.

Piece of code:

```
void on_new_activate (GtkMenuItem *menuitem, gpointer user_data)
{

  int rand, x;

  gtk_statusbar_push (GTK_STATUSBAR(statusbar1), 0, "Welcome to sliders");
  move_no=0;

  if (GTK_IS_WIDGET(image) && GTK_IS_WIDGET(image->parent)) //**error here**
  {
    gtk_object_ref (GTK_OBJECT(image));
    gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(alignment1), image);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(alignment1), table1);
    gtk_widget_show (table1);
  }

  for (x=0; x<=14; x++)
  {
    rand = abs(g_rand_int ( g_rand_new () )) % 15;
    if (x!=rand)
       swap_buttons (x, rand);
  }

}
```

Comment: That tutorial is for GTK+ 2. You will need to find a different tutorial, such as the one [in the GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). For that particular example, the best thing to do is to rewrite it so it doesn't need to get the parent of `image` out of the `image` itself, but rather to pass it around directly.

Comment: @andlabs It might be even worse - looking at the source, it is possible that it is in fact for GTK+ 1!

Answer (score 2):

The parent container is no longer exposed as a member. Instead of accessing `image->parent`, call [`gtk_widget_get_parent(image)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-parent).

In the long term, as pointed out by @andlabs, you are best off finding a tutorial that covers GTK+ version 3, which you are using.